# Making all classes in module available everywhere in module

Tags: ruby, github, module, rubygems

I'm writing a console utility for managing Github issues and I've run into a `undefined method` error.

My app is structured the following way

```
gissues.rb # includes all files in subfolders

Gissues
    github.rb #Gissues::Github general github stuff

    commands.rb #Gissues::commands subclass of Thor (whatisthor.com), general command stuff

    cli.rb #subclass of commands, lists command shortcuts and subcommands

    commands

        user.rb #Command::User subclass of Gissues::Commands holds logic for github user related commands like signin, signout, whoami

    github

        user.rb #Github::User subclass of Gissues::Github holds logic for communicating with github for authentication (checking credentials)
```

I defined methods for communicating with Github in user.rb inside the github folder. I want to use these methods in user.rb defined in the commands folder but when I do, it seems outside the scope and I get a method not defined error.

user.rb (commands) looks like this

```
module Gissues
    class Command::User < Gissues::Command
        desc "signin", "Starts loging sequence"
        def signin
            Gissues::Github::User::request_token
        end
     end
end
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
/Users/someone/RubymineProjects/Gissues/lib/gissues/commands/user.rb:9:in `signin': undefined method `request_token' for Gissues::Github::User:Class (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Edit: [image: This image may make the structure more clear] This image may make the structure more clear

Comment: You might explicitly `require_relative '../github/user'` or you have to check that `github/user` is required *before* `command/user` in topmost file.

Answer (score 0):

If your top-level module has an explicit `require` for all submodules, this won't be an issue. If you're loading a bottom-level module directly, then nothing else will really be defined. That's where the problem arises.

A typical module looks like:

```
module Gissues
  require 'gissues/command'
  require 'gissues/user'
end
```

These need to be listed in order of their dependency. It is possible, though not recommended, to use `autoload` to accomplish the same task.

So long as they are all loaded in the correct order you should be good to go.

It's worth noting that methods should be called as `Gissues::Github::User.request_token` with a dot before the method. The `::` notation is usually reserved for class names or constants, like `Gissues::CONST` vs. `Gissues.method_name`.

Comment: Calling `require` like this is misleading; it makes it look like it is scoped to `Gissues` somehow. `require` simply runs the code in the file. Period. It doesn't scope it to anything. Therefore, it is much clearer to put calls to `require` at the top-level instead of inside a module or class definition expression.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's a matter of preference, they can go at the end of the file. Since they're evaluated on an immediate basis, the end result is the same. Note that the `require` statement can't be at the top of the file here as those sub-modules may depend on `Gissues` being defined. The way I have it here it's impossible to get it wrong.

Comment: In this case, it could be at the end of the file at the top-level, or directly after the module definition expression at the top-level. There are plenty of questions here on StackOverflow, where the problem is that the OP assumes that putting a call to `require` inside a module definition expression will somehow scope the code in the file inside the module. So, this seems a common misconception, and simply never writing a call to `require` inside a module definition expression helps to combat this misconception. That's why I generally try to avoid it.

Comment: If you assign a constant inside a module definition expression, the constant becomes scoped to that module, if you write a method definition expression inside a module definition expression, the method becomes an instance method of that module, if you assign an instance variable inside a module definition expression, the instance variable becomes an instance variable of the module object itself. I can kind of see the symmetry here that leads to that misconception.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That `require` is not scoped is pretty fundamental to Ruby, so if there's confusion there that's beyond my control. When it comes to organizing code, a lot of this is personal preference.

Comment: Your answer sounds really logical, yet I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I edited my question with a screenshot of the project

Comment: Are you sure `request_token` is a class method?

Comment: @RoemerBakker That's an instance method. You can't call it without having an instance of the object. Also your indentation is all over the place. I hope your original source is cleaner.

Comment: @tadman Oh my God thank you so much. I'm new to Ruby and didn't know the difference. It works now! And yes, the original source looks better ;)

Comment: @RoemerBakker If you're coming at Ruby from other languages, there's a subtle but important difference between class methods, otherwise known as singleton methods, or static methods, and instance methods. Hope that helps!